# sql multi value dimension

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

(This is my first question ever asked so please bear with me here guys)

I created a data warehouse on SQL Server 2014 Enterprise and I'm struggling mapping a fact to multiple values in one dimension.

Imagine a data center with servers reserved for specific services and customers.
Those servers have specific components like network adapters, cpus or operating systems.

A few rows from my fact table would look like this:

```
ServerID   CustomerID   OSID   ServiceID   NetworkGroupID  CPUID
1           1            1        1           1               1
2           1            2        1           2               1
3           2            1        2           2               2
```

Server 1 and 2 belong to Customer 1. Server 1 is running OS 1, the other OS 2. Both provide Service 1.
Server 1 has **a set** of network adapters identified as '1', the other 2. These sets contain multiple network adapters (some virtual, some physical).

My Network Dimension has the attributes ID and NetworkAdapterName and I would need the ID to appear multiple times like so:

```
ID   NetworkAdapterName
1      IntelAdapter#1
1      IntelAdapter#2
1      VirtualAdapter#1
2      IntelAdapter#1
2      DellAdapter#1
3      VirtualAdapter#1
3      VirtualAdapter#2
```

I figured I would need some kind of sub dimension acting as a bridge like so:

```
NetworkGroupID   NetworkID
  1              1
  1              2
  1              3
  2              1
  2              5
  3              3
  3              4

NetworkID NetworkAdapterName
1         IntelAdapter#1
2         IntelAdapter#2
3         VirtualAdapter#1
4         VirtualAdapter#2
5         DellAdapter#1
```

But then how would I be able to define a primary key or a relation in general from the fact table to the bridge dimension, since there are multiple appearances of the same value as NetworkGroupID?

(The same occurs with the CPU and OS but once I get it working for the network adapters I would be able to do it for other components as well.)

Edit:
In the end I want to build a cube in SSAS that can show me the multiple components one server has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a table (or dimension) defining `NetworkGroup`:

```
CREATE TABLE NetworkGroup (
    NetworkGroupID int          not null PRIMARY KEY,
    Name           nvarchar(50) null
);
```

Then use your "bridge" table (a.k.a. [Junction Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)) to join it with your `Network` table:

```
CREATE TABLE NetworkGroupNetwork (
    NetworkGroupID int not null,
    NetworkID      int not null,

    CONSTRAINT PK_NetworkGroupNetwork
        PRIMARY KEY (NetworkGroupID, NetworkID),

    CONSTRAINT FK_NetworkGroupNetwork_NetworkGroup
        FOREIGN KEY (NetworkGroupID)
        REFERENCES NetworkGroup (NetworkGroupID),

    CONSTRAINT FK_NetworkGroupNetwork_Network
        FOREIGN KEY (NetworkID)
        REFERENCES Network (NetworkID)
);
```

Comment: [Design Tip #124 Alternatives for Multi-valued Dimensions](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2010/06/design-tip-124-alternatives-for-multi-valued-dimensions/) is a worthwhile read, too.

Comment: This is what I was thinking about but how would I be able to create a constraint from the PK NetworkGroup to the composite PK in NetworkGroupNetwork?

Comment: It is the other way around; The constraint is from one of the columns in `NetworkGroupNetwork` to the PK of `NetworkGroup`. Similar to what you have between your Fact table (column CustomerID) and Customer table.

Comment: I feel silly now, of course that works :D Looks promising, I will need a few more minutes to verify the result. I still have to figure out how to put those into my cube in SSAS

Comment: Unfortunately I can't work out how SSAS recognizes the bridge as bridge and not as a dimension. Just to verify the relations are correct now:

factTable with NetworkGroupID has a foreign key reference to NetworkGroup(NetworkGroupID) which is being referenced via a foreign key from NetworkGroupNetwork(NetworkGroupID) which is then again being referenced by dimNetwork(NetworkID).

Comment: NetworkGroupNetwork(NetworkGroupID) references NetworkGroup(NetworkGroupID).
NetworkGroupNetwork(NetworkID) references dimNetwork(NetworkID).

Comment: exactly ;) thanks for your help! in SSAS I had to define NetworkGroupNetwork as another measure group (fact table) and make a many-to-many relation between my original fact table and dimNetwork via NetworkGroupNetwork